# C# generics and casting

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I've come across a function in our code base throwing an error:

```
public static T InternalData<T>()
{
    return (T)"100";
}
```

Obviously I've simplified the code and added the "100" as a literal string value. T is of type `int`.

It throws a:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

It seems that you can't implicitly convert a string to `int` in C#, how can I fix this code so that it can handle converting any generic type?

The actual code would look something like this:

```
public static T InternalData<T>()
{
    return (T) something (not sure of type or data);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
public static T InternalData<T>(object data)
{
     return (T) Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(T));
}
```

This works for types that implement the `IConvertible` interface (which `Int32` and `String` does).

Comment: I've never used ChangeType before, wasn't aware the method existed - thank you - testing now!

Answer (score 7):

One possibility would be to use

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(yourValue, typeof(T));
```

Please note that this will throw an exception, if `yourValue` isn't an instance of a type that implements `IConvertible`. It will also throw an exception if the value itself can't be converted, for example if you have "abc" instead of "100".

Answer (score 4):

Use `Convert.ChangeType`.

```
public static T InternalData<T>()
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType("100", typeof (T));
}
```

It'll still throw an error if the values can't be converted, but it will not try to do a direct cast.  It can convert strings to ints ok.

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse casting and converting! If the true type of an expression is not known to the compiler, e.g. because it is typed as `object`, and you know its inherent type, you can tell the C# compiler, "Hey, I know its a `int`, so please treat it as a `int`".

```
 (int)expression
```

In your case the expression is a string expression that cannot be casted to `int`, simply beacuase it is not an `int`. However, you can convert the string to `int` if it represents a valid integer. Moreover the result type of your conversion is unknown because its generic. Use `(T)Convert.ChangeType(...)` as others have already suggested.